# Get Instance of Metadata block

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am programming a 1.11.2 Minecraft mod, and I need to obtain an instance of a block with specific metadata.

```
public BIGOre(String CustomOreDictName, String UnlocalizedBlockName, int Metadata, String Mod)
{
    Block a;
    a = Block.getBlockFromName(UnlocalizedBlockName);

    NonNullList<ItemStack> SubBlocks = NonNullList.create();
    a.getSubBlocks(Item.getItemFromBlock(a), a.getCreativeTabToDisplayOn(), SubBlocks);
    this.GetBlock = Block.getBlockFromItem(SubBlocks.get(Metadata).getItem());
}
```

My current attempt at doing this finds a block by unlocalized name. Then (here is the part that isn't working) gets all of the sub blocks into a list, then chooses the correct one.

How do I obtain a block with a specified metadata from the unlocalized name, and metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.8 and above, Minecraft uses the `IBlockState` system to represent the combination of a block in the world, so your field `GetBlock` should be an `IBlockState` not a `Block` if you want to accurately represent a block with a specific metadata. You can use `a.getStateFromMeta(Metadata)` to obtain the `IBlockState` corresponding to that metadata value.

Side note, you shouldn't be using unlocalized names for this as they are subject to change at the whim of another mod developer. You should use the registry name which very, very rarely changes between versions because it's used for storing blocks in the world. To look up a block by a String with it's registry name use `ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS.getValue(new ResourceLocation(registryName))`.